# Why is the Lebesgue integral linear when only one summand is integrable?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a measure space, $(f_n)_n$ measurable for all $n$, and $f$ measurable, non-negative and integrable such that $f_n \le f$ for all $n$. Then $\int _X \limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n d\mu \ge \limsup _{n\to \infty} \int _X f_n d\mu$.
In the proof I saw for this statement, we define $h_n = f - f_n$. We have that $$\int _X \liminf _{n\to \infty} h_n d\mu= \int _X \liminf _{n\to \infty} (f - f_n) d\mu = \int _X (f + \liminf _{n\to \infty} (-f_n)) d\mu = \int _X f d\mu + \int _X \liminf _{n\to \infty} (-f_n) d\mu$$
The explanation for the last equality is that $f$ is integrable. However, to use linearity we need all summands to be integrable.
Why can we use it here?

Thanks.

Comment: The $f_n$ are either positive or integrable, otherwise $\limsup_{n\to\infty }\int f_n$ has no sense... so of course $\int(f_n-f)=\int f_n-\int f$ (notice that it holds even if $\int f_n=\infty $)

Comment: $\int (f+g)d\mu=\int fd\mu +\int gd\mu$ if at least one of $f,g$ is integrable and the other integral exists.

Comment: I get it, thanks